# Is there any way to keep the ".0" on a number during serialization?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a property on my pojo that is a double. I'd like for it to get serialized out to the json as 1.0 vs 1. Jackson seems hell bent on removing the .0. Looking around, I tried writing a custom serializer and I call `jgen.writeRaw(": 1.0")` just for testing and it STILL removes it. Only way to preserve it seems to be to write it out as a string?

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to do so?

Comment: This looks like a classic [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question

Comment: There is no .0 to keep. How you *display* the value is entirely up to you. How Jackson chooses to serialize it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to represent the number as 1.0 in JavaScript/JSON (which I presume you're working with due to the tag `jackson`; if not, please clarify your question). JavaScript has only one [Number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). If you have a client program that is misinterpreting it as an integer, that should be corrected on the client-side.